# C++ Google Protocol Buffers: assign binary stream to protobuf object

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following protoc file:

```
message DataChunk{
    required bool isHash=1;
    required int64 hash=2;
    required string data=3;
}

message responseBody{
    repeated DataChunk dataChunk=1;
}
```

And I have the following C++ function:

```
void eamorr(string data){   //data is a protocol buffer stream converted to a string
    responseBody rb;

    rb=some_function_of(data);   //what to do here?
}
```

The string "data" was created using:

```
...
std::ostringstream stream;
rb.SerializeToOstream(&stream);
string protobufStream = stream.str();
...
```

My question is: how do I convert a string to a protoc object so I can access the member elements? Please bear in mind that I'm very new to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
rb.ParseFromString(data)
```

Comment: Greetings, thanks for that. It's working now. Sorry for belated reply.

Comment: What if there is no `ParseFromString` method generated?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the data object why not make :

```
responseBody rb; //this is your proto object;
rb.SerializeToString(&data);
```

Then on deserializing:

```
void eamorr(string data){
    responseBody rb;
    rb.ParseFromString(data);
}
```